# BASH: copy all the files of a folder to other folder

Tags: bash, shell, copy

I want to copy notebooks with extension .ipynb from one folder to other.
And I am writing my first bash script.sh

```
CURRENT=${PWD}
cp "$CURRENT/notebooks/*.ipynb" "/home/jovyan/shared/public/whatever"
```

result:

```
cp: cannot stat '/home/name/utils/notebooks/*.ipynb': No such file or directory
```

but '/home/name/utils/notebooks/ EXISTS
and it has notebooks.

Where is the error in the command here?

is it possible to build also a command telling "all the notebooks that which name starts by py"

Thanks

Comment: Quoted globs won't expand, use `"$CURRENT/notebooks/"*.ipynb`

Comment: There's also `./notebooks/*.ipynb` instead of `$PWD`.

Comment: Sorry to have edited the question, I added another question. perhaps its easy for you. This is my first ever bash script

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write

```
cp notebooks/*.ipynb "/home/jovyan/shared/public/whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoted globs will not expand.

> all the notebooks that which name starts by py

This moves the files to a path in the *current* home directory:

```
cp ./notebooks/py*.ipynb ~/shared/public/whatever/
```

If you need the home directory of one specific user (regardless of who is running the command), you can use:

```
cp ./notebooks/py*.ipynb ~jovyan/shared/public/whatever/
```

You may also need full paths:

```
cp ~/utils/notebooks/py*.ipynb ~/shared/public/whatever/
```

An explanation of tilde expansion: `~` (unquoted) expands to the home directory of the current user, whilst `~jovyan` expands to the home directory of user `jovyan`, even if you are logged in as a different user. Tilde expansion is a [feature of the POSIX shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01), and not bash specific.

Comment: You don't need the `./` prefix on the paths here. It basically means "in/starting from the current directory", which is implicit in most situations, including this one. (There are a few situations where it's *not* implicit, and those are where you might need a `./` prefix.)

Comment: That's true, I just prefer it if the relative path contains multiple elements (sub-directories).